# resource xml file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-2, xml-serialization

i have been given a task to make a resource xml file for the static content of our website so that we can look-up for the content in that xml file against a particular id and display it. For example if we have written "Welcome to xyz.com" on our home page it should be stored in the xml file like

```
<word>
  <add Key="welcome" value="Welcome to xyz.com" />
</word>

<word>
  <add key="key1" value="some other static content" />
</word>
```

so we will be able to display the text by id="welcome"...
plz help.

accessing the resource file as

```
string key = "Home";
             string resourceValue = string.Empty;
             string resourceFile = "Resource";//name of my resource file Resource.resx

             string filePath =System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

             ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);


             resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
```

and getting the following error

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk.
baseName: Resource  locationInfo: <null>  fileName: Resource.resources
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a specific question. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Look into using Resource (resx) files in Visual Studio.

Comment: i dont know how to do it, i do knw that ill have to use a xml reader but how exactly?

Comment: i have created a resource file in my project added some values in it but when i tried to access the file i got the following error

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) on disk.
baseName: Resource  locationInfo: <null>  fileName: Resource.resources"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an XML format like this:

```
<Page Id="Home">
    <Elements>
        <Element Id="welcome">
            <Value>Welcome to xyz.com</Value>
        </Element>

        <Element Id="key1">
            <Value>some other static content</Value>
        </Element>      
    </Elements>
</Page>
```

Why?  My first thought is that each page needs it own id.  So I have shown a page called "Home" with two Elements.  Also by using tags rather than attributes sou can use CDATA sections [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA] in case you have characters that need to be escaped.  Otherwise you'll have to transform <,>,& and that gets ugly.

```
<Element Id="key1">
    <Value><![CDATA[some other static content with < > in it!]]></Value>
</Element>
```

Or how about it you want to include a div? with a class?

```
<Element Id="key1">
    <Value><![CDATA[<div class="wrapper">some other static content with in it!</div>]]></Value>
</Element>
```

It's better.

In general, I use tags more than attributes.  It's easier to find tags using XPath.